# Switch between two opened editors

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

I have two editors opened, one on the left and one on the right. How to switch between them? I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd> but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It works, using the `1`, `2` keys above the letters (not the keypad). Events in the keyboard shortcuts panel are under `workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup` and so on.

You can also bind commands such as `workbench.action.navigateRight` and so on to move focus between panels.

Comment: ah dang, sorry didn't pay attention

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Shift+P` show all commands, search `Preference: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` and open it, then you can search the action or shortcuts.

for this problem,search`focusFirstEditorgroup`,you can see the shortcut,change as you like.then search`foucusSecondEditorGroup` and so on.

Comment: on my list there no either both names you given. Remember this is visual studio, not visual studio code

Comment: sorry not pay attention to it.I don't use visual studio,maybe use `alt+1/2/3` works.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019